# Design of an FSM (REGEX)

Tags: regex, fsm

I need to design an FSM that recognizes sequences of 1s and 0s that have the pattern 00 an odd number of times admiting overlaps( actually I just need the REGEX but I need to show a table)

Comment: I don't think regular expressions can count overlaps.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: You can design an FSM by drawing on a piece of paper.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.